# Loading image gives a 403 error with Jquery call/post

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-403

Hi guys i want to use an load image during the .ajax request with Jquery.
I found some tutorial on internet to achieve this. But i get 403 error...

Here some code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "person_controller.php?action=newConsult",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(div){
            $("#generateDiv").html('<img src="css/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" />');
            $('#generateDiv').load(div);
        },
    });
```

When i run the above code, firebug gives me 403 error(you don't have permission to access).
But i am only loading the image?!? Without the image it does work.

The path of image is correct i see the image spinning but firebug gives me the 403 error.
How is this possible when i run this application on localhost?

Comment: Should you be using `type: "POST"` with a URL containing `GET` parameters?

Comment: What is the value of "div"?  Why would you set the HTML content of an element right before loading something else into it?

Comment: @Pointy: Looks like it's a "content is loading" animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try the following which sets the loading image prior to the request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "person_controller.php?action=newConsult",
    data: dataString,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#generateDiv").html('<img src="css/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" />');
    },
    success: function(div){            
        $('#generateDiv').html(div);
    },
});
```

Alternativly, you could use the BlockUI jQuery plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Comment: When i use both divs to .html instead of load it does work.
But now i don't see any loader image is there a way to slow down this i tried with .fadeIn('slow') still doenst show the image. Tnx for you help